# Nsimage draw in rect but the image is blurry?

Tags: macos, nsimage, drawinrect

designer give me picture like this [image]

But when I use drawInRect API draw the picture in context, the picture is like this [image]

The size of the rect is just the size of the image.And the image is @1x and @2x.

the difference is very clear, the picture is blurry and there is a gray line in the right of image, and My imac is retina resolution.

================================================
I have found the reason,

```
[self.headLeftImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(100,
                                        100,
                                        self.headLeftImage.size.width,
                                        self.headLeftImage.size.height)];




CGContextRef context = (CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, self.center.x , self.center.y);

[self.headLeftImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(100,
                                        100,
                                        self.headLeftImage.size.width,
                                        self.headLeftImage.size.height)];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

And in the first draw the image will not blur, but after translate the image is blurry. Just like the picture:[image]

Comment: What is the type of the image in the actual app? Is it a bitmap or vector format? What rect are you supplying to the draw call?

Comment: I have edited my description, thx.

Comment: @Ken the type is png~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're translating the context to a non-integral pixel location. Then, the draw is honoring your request to put the image at a non-integral position, which causes it to be anti-aliased and color in some pixels partially.

You should convert the center point to device space, integral-ize it (e.g. by using `floor()`), and then convert it back. Use `CGContextConvertPointToDeviceSpace()` and `CGContextConvertPointToUserSpace()` to do the conversions. That does the right thing for Retina and non-Retina displays.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just know that I should click the check to mark the accepted answer.